# Zend Framework 2 model class not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a model in src\Front\Model\FrontModel.php

I am trying to extend it in my IndexController i have this in my Module.php:

`use Front\Model\FrontModel;`

But i always get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Front\Model\FrontModel' not found in
>
> C:\Apache24\htdocs\cartbiz\module\Front\src\Front\Controller\IndexController.php
>   on line 16

I have this in my IndexController where i am trying to extend my model my Controller  resides in src\Front\Controller\IndexController.php

```
namespace Front\Controller;
use Front\Model\FrontModel;

class IndexController extends FrontModel
{


/* Initialize Controller */

public function initAction()
{
    parent::initAction();
}
}
```

I have this as my model class my model class resides in  src\Front\Model\FrontModel.php

```
namespace Front\Model\FrontModel;   
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
class FrontModel extends AbstractActionController
{

    /* Application initializer 
    ** All front application logic
    */

    public function __construct ()
    {
        die('ssss');

        $this->_viewManager=new ViewModel;
        $this->_viewManager->setTemplate('front/index/index');
        return $this->_viewManager;


    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the `namespace` statement written in the `src\Front\Model\FrontModel.php` file? i.e. above the `class FrontModel extends AbstractActionController` line.

Comment: sorry please see my edit now :)

Comment: i don't get the point of your above implementation

Comment: Actually i want to create a global model for my front module in which their are various sub controllers like index controller for homepage for controlling the frontend of my application Front model  can instantiate the Application necessary things like header, footer widgets if any etc

Comment: Look at @AlexP's answer. The error you get is because of your namespaces are not right. `FrontModel` class is using the namespace `Front\Model\FrontModel` while it should be `Front\Model` your controller is looking for `Front\Model\FrontModel` class but with your setup you should: `use Front\Model\FrontModel\FrontModel` in your controller as it doesn't know the class, since you're currently using a namespace. I'm not creating a new answer as @AlexP is already covering it.

Comment: Hey Thanks Kudos i figured it our earlier but cant posted my answer because i cant until 8 hours are passed here... Hope you would have posted answer with proposed changes i would have marked it as solved :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `namespace` to the `FontModel` class.

```
namespace Front\Model;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class FrontModel extends AbstractActionController
{}
```

Also, it's worth noting that your naming conventions could lead to confusion. I would recommend placing all the controllers in the controller folder, and reading up on the [coding standards](https://zf2-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/coding.standard.html#naming-conventions).

Comment: Bump: OP is using `namespace Front\Model\FrontModel` in `FrontModel` while he should use `namespace Front\Model` instead, like you have in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works

```
namespace Front\Model;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class FrontModel extends AbstractActionController
{

    /* Application initializer 
    ** All front application logic
    */

    public function __construct ()
    {
        die('ssss');

        $this->_viewManager=new ViewModel;
        $this->_viewManager->setTemplate('front/index/index');
        return $this->_viewManager;


    }
}
```

Comment: Didnt worked out Please see my edit may be it can help